# Symfony2 Form query_builder - allow null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, query-builder

In Symfony2 forms, when trying to get entities, Symfony expects to receive QueryBuilder object, but sometimes there are no entities returned. In that case, an error message appears:

> Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "NULL" given

How to make query_builder to allow option that there are no entities available.

```
$builder
    ->add('client', 'entity', array(
        'class'         => 'Faktura\FakturaBundle\Entity\Client',
        'query_builder' => function(\Web\MyBundle\Repository\ClientRepository $er) use ($company){
            return $er->getClients($company);
    ))
;
```

*ClientRepository.php*

```
public function getClients($company)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c')
        ->where('c.company = :company')
        ->setParameter('company', $company)
        ->getQuery();

    return $qb->getResult();
}
```

Actually, it's just basic `$er->findBy(array('company' => $company))` method
but I use custom `getClients()` method

Comment: paste here body of ```getClients```.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Closure should return QueryBuilder object, not results of it.

Your *ClientRepository* should look like:

```
public function getClients($company)
{
    $qb = $this->getClientsQueryBuilder($company);
    return  $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}

public function getClientsQueryBuilder($company)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c')
        ->where('c.company = :company')
        ->setParameter('company', $company);

}
```

And then you need to use `getClientQueryBuilder` in your Closure.

```
$builder
    ->add('client', 'entity', array(
        'class'         => 'Faktura\FakturaBundle\Entity\Client',
        'query_builder' => function(\Web\MyBundle\Repository\ClientRepository $er) use ($company){
            return $er->getClientsQueryBuilder($company);
    ))
;
```